# Whats the maximum number of electrons that can fit into the outer shell of boron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms, physical-chemistry

Whats the maximum number of electrons that can fit into the outer shell of boron? Like silicon has 4 electrons in the outer shell but the maximum it can hold is 8 electrons so whats the maximum number of electrons that can fit into the outer shell of boron which has 3 electrons but can it hold more in the outershell?

Comment: A quick reference is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_electron#The_number_of_valence_electrons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron) can conceivably fit a maximum of 8 electrons in its outer shell.  This could be achieved through boron covalently bonding with a non-metal (as boron is a metalloid).

It is in the 2nd period (row) of the periodic table, hence has 2 'shells', following the [2n<sup>2</sup> pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell) for maximum amount of outer shell electrons (where 'n' is the amount of 'shells' the element has).